# Magento 2.3.1 js error 500

Tags: magento2, customer-account, jquery

In Magento 2.3.1 everything I put a product in Wishlist I get this error in console of all browsers:

```
GET https://mystore.com/el/customer/section/load/?sections=customer%2Ccompare-products%2Clast-ordered-items%2Cdirectory-data%2Ccaptcha%2Creview%2Cwishlist%2Cinstant-purchase%2Cmultiplewishlist%2Cpersistent%2Crecently_viewed_product%2Crecently_compared_product%2Cproduct_data_storage%2Cpaypal-billing-agreement%2Cmessages&force_new_section_timestamp=false&_=1561827509049 500 error jQuery.js:10254
```

I can't figure out why. If I remove the product everything is fine.
No errors in logs.
Syntax of the file is using Ajax to call Magento controller seems fine. But controller returns 500 error.

Does anyone please advice where to look?